# Multicraft doesn't come up with non-code content

Tags: php

[image: Img]

I'm trying to install Multicraft on my Raspberry Pi running Ubuntu Server, and it keeps coming up with this code:

```
<?php
/**
 *
 *   Copyright Â© 2010-2021 by xhost.ch GmbH
 *
 *   All rights reserved.
 *
 **/

$yii = dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/yii/yii.php';
$config = dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/internal/application.php';

// uncomment the following line to enable more detailed error messages
//defined('YII_DEBUG') or define('YII_DEBUG',true);
// how many levels of call stack should be shown in each log message
defined('YII_TRACE_LEVEL') or define('YII_TRACE_LEVEL',3);

if (!@file_exists(dirname(__FILE__).'/protected/config/config.php'))
    header('Location: install.php');
else
{
    require_once($yii);
    Yii::createWebApplication($config)->run();
}
```

Comment: I have tried restarting the device.

Comment: After Researching, I found somebody having the same problem but never solving it.
https://www.linode.com/community/questions/21852/cant-access-multicraft-installation-page

Comment: NVM they solved it